# Avoiding running the same MySQL script multiple times

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

I have a script like this:

```
$result = array();
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM servers"; //doesn't really matter what this MySQL script is

//storing the same query in two different variables
$result[0] = mysql_query($sql);
$result[1] = $result[0];

for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {

    $result[0] = $result[1];

    while($ret = mysql_fetch_array($result[0]) {
        //run some code
    }

}
```

Unfortunately, the above code executes once and then for the next iterations returns nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to do here ??

Comment: I'm trying to make it so that instead of running mysql_query($sql) inside the for loop, which makes it so that you have to do 3 mysql operations, I just store the variable and keep restoring it inside the for loop to avoid extra mysql searches.

Comment: Instead of doing that store data in an array first place then do whatever you want to do.

Comment: not quite following why you are repeating iterating over the result set 3 times, surely as the result set is the same each time all 3 iterations will have the 'run some code' results?

Comment: Storing it in an array worked.
If I kept using the same variable, mysql_fetch_array runs through the whole thing in the while loop and then I need to redo the mysql_query to start over. (as far as I know)

Comment: Why would you create three references? Its not good for performance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not so sure what are you trying to do. but if i understand, try this. remove the for loop, just put the while loop and do what ever you want to.

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM servers";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
    while($ret = mysql_fetch_array($result) {
        //run some code
        echo $ret['Name'];
    }
}
```

you will get all 3 records in each iteration and do what ever process you want to do for each record. no need to make a three 3 query for 3 records. One query will have all records and do while loop to get each record. hope it helps.